# Not sure if i'm using exec properly to pass to another program

Tags: c, fork

I have the execlp() call:

```c
execlp("Sequence.c", "Sequence.c", data, NULL);
```

I'm not sure I'm passing execlp() correctly because the Sequence.c never outputs anything. The current output is only as shown below but I am not too sure what I am doing incorrectly at the moment. From what I know, after I call execlp(), the forked child should run Sequence instead of another instance of Begin, while the parent waits for the forked child to return before running further code.

Comment: You can only run executable programs, not C code.

Comment: `if (argc < 2) { perror(...);}` doesn't make any sense.  You have not set `errno`, so you may wind up with error messages like `Missing filename as argument\n: Not a typewriter\n`.  Just do `fprintf(stderr, "Missing argument\n")`

Comment: And `perror("File could not be opened\n")` is much better written as `perror(fileName)`.

Answer (score 1):

You should always check for errors. `execlp` never returns on success, so the "correct" way to call `execlp` is:

```
execlp (progname, arg0, arg1, ...., (char *)NULL);
/* If we reach this point, something failed */
perror("execlp failed");
_exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

It is important to call `_exit` after `execlp` returns, otherwise we have two processes running the same code. Typically we don't want that. We call `_exit` rather than `exit`, since `exit` does some cleanup, including flushing of buffers. The child process has copies of those buffers, and we don't want them to be flushed twice.

If you give us the error message from `perror` we could maybe help you. Without error messages there is not much we can do. Except the fact that you are trying to call an executable named `*.c`, makes us suspect that you are trying to execute a source-file. You know that unless you have a c-code interpreter, c-programs must be compiled, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, when you use **execlp** you are calling **Sequence.c**, but I'm not sure because I've always use this form **./Sequence**, I'm not calling this with c file, but with object file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).